# Wrong radio input checked on load based on ng-model and ng-value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, object

I have some basic example of form with [radio inputs DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/9irYerDwcaeGelm07Xbf?p=preview):

```
<form class="some-inputs">
    <div ng-repeat="da in data">
      <span>{{$index}}: {{da}}</span>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="lock-{{$index}}"
               name="lock-choice-{{$index}}"
               ng-model="mdl['account-{{$index}}']['blocked']"
               ng-value="da.blocked">
        <span>blocked</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="unrealized-{{$index}}"
               name="lock-choice-{{$index}}"
               ng-model="mdl['account-{{$index}}']['unrealized']"
               ng-value="da.unrealized">
        <span>not blocked</span>
      </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, I'm not using ng-checked, just ng-model and ng-value.
Also there are objects with properties printed, for comparison purposes.

Question is, why in every example, second radio button is checked, even if it's value is false - thus first radio which is truthy should be checked - ?

When I delete ng-value attributes from input, no radios are checked, even if properties from ng-models already have values which could make it happen..

Comment: The `ng-value` directive takes an AngularJS expression. See [Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#why-mixing-interpolation-and-expressions-is-bad-practice-)

Comment: The interpolation directive `{{ }}` converts the boolean `false` to the string `"false"`. In JavaScript, the string `"false"` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: Ok, got rid of interpolation and now no radio is ckecked by default.
Even modified code a bit and started using another object as a models source.
When click some radio, other will be clicked as well in a weird manner.
Still can't figure out whats wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing `ng-repeat` with objects, use `(key, value)` as the iterator:

```
̶<̶d̶i̶v̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶r̶e̶p̶e̶a̶t̶=̶"̶d̶a̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶"̶>̶
<div ng-repeat="(key,da) in data">
```

It makes the HTML clearer.

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/mk2IqVw8qoOLfB9XMbd3?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    "account-0":{
      "blocked":true,
    },
    "account-1":{
      "blocked":false,
    },
    "account-2":{
      "blocked":false,
    },
    "account-3":{
      "blocked":true,
    }
  };
  $scope.mdl = {};
  angular.forEach($scope.data, (value, key)=> {
    $scope.mdl[key] = {choice: value.blocked?'blocked':'not blocked'};
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="form1">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, da) in data">
      <span>{{key}}</span>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="{{key}}-blocked"
               name="block-choice-{{key}}"
               ng-model="mdl[key].choice"
               ng-value="'blocked'">
        <span>blocked</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="{{key}}-not-blocked"
               name="block-choice-{{key}}" 
               ng-model="mdl[key].choice"
               ng-value="'not blocked'">
        <span>not blocked</span>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" id="{{key}}-undecided"
               name="block-choice-{{key}}" 
               ng-model="mdl[key].choice"
               ng-value="'undecided'">
        <span>undecided</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in mdl">
    {{k}} {{v}}
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works finally!
My problem was using ng-model="mdl['account-{{$index}}']['unrealized']" instead simpler ng-model="mdl[key].choice" - the case was probably using interpolation inside ng-model.